# Formato shapefile para gráfico con leaflet en R

Tags: r

Intento utilizar la cartografía de las secciones censales del INE, he descargado el archivo shapefile de 2019 desde https://www.ine.es/ss/Satellite?L=es_ES&c=Page&cid=1259952026632&p=1259952026632&pagename=ProductosYServicios%2FPYSLayout

Utilizando gvSIG he filtrado una selección de secciones censales y la he exportado en formato shapefile. 
Tipo: MULTIPOLYGON
Subtipo: 2D
Codificación: UTF-8
EPSG:4326

En R he importado utilizando el package "sf":

```
geoseccionesmurcia <- st_read("archivo.shp")
Reading layer `Secciones Censales Murcia Municipio' from data source `C:\Users\JosÃ©Carlos\Google Drive\Personal\Profesional\EstadÃ­stica\R-project\directorio trabajo\cartografÃ­a secciones censales 30030 murcia municipio\Secciones Censales Murcia Municipio.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 387 features and 23 fields
geometry type:  POLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -1.384834 ymin: 37.71601 xmax: -0.8508899 ymax: 38.11792
epsg (SRID):    4326
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

He realizado un `summary(geoseccionesmurcia)`:

geometry
 GEOMETRYCOLLECTION:  2
 POLYGON           :387
 epsg:4326         :  0
 +proj=long...     :  0

El archivo shapefile importado puedo mostrarlo usuando `plot()`, pero cuando intento crear el gráfico con leaflet en R:

```
Error in to_ring.default(x) : 
  Don't know how to get polygon data from object of class XY,GEOMETRYCOLLECTION,sfg
```

Gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando utilizaba simplemente `plot()` con el archivo shapefile importado se generaba el mapa sin dar ningún error.

PERO, para hacer el gráfico utilizo además del archivo shapefile con los polígonos de las secciones, un archivo con la renta de las secciones, el problema se producía cuando unía ambos data.frame, porque el segundo, el que contiene la renta de las secciones, tiene dos registros (secciones) más que el primero, es decir, dos secciones que no se encuentran en el shapefile.

Estaba utilizando `merge(...,all=T)`, es decir, se incorporaban dos registros (secciones) del archivo de renta que no tienen definida geometría espacial, y de ahí el error al intentar visualizar el mapa.